# Flex Mobile Project Warning "warning: unable to bind to property 'myData' on class 'com.amec.controls.Text::TextListView'"

Tags: sqlite, apache-flex, data-binding, flash-builder, flex-mobile

So on a Flex Mobile Project I am trying to bind the results from a Select SQLLite query to a view.  But it is not displaying results and I get the following

```
 warning: unable to bind to property 'myData' on class 'com.amec.controls.Text::TextListView'
```

From FLash Builder.  Below is my view class.  What is it I am missing or doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<amec:BaseAddView xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
              xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
              xmlns:amec="com.amec.Components.*"
              creationComplete="vw_creationCompleteHandler(event)" title="TextListView">
<amec:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="5"/>
</amec:layout>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.amec.BaseSql;
        import com.amec.MenuMessage;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;


        [Bindable]private var resultArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;


        protected function vw_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {

        }

        private function get myData():ArrayCollection
        {

            var conn:BaseSql = new BaseSql();
            conn.stmt.text = "SELECT DMV_VALUE_1 FROM DOMAIN_VALUE WHERE DMV_DMN_ID = :id";
            x.parameters[":id"] = id;
            x.sqlConnection = conn.stmt.sqlConnection;
            var x:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement;

            x.text = conn.stmt.text;

            x.execute();
            var result:Array = conn.stmt.getResult().data;
            var r:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();


            if (result)
            {      
                r.source = result;        
                return r;
            } else {
                return null;
            }


        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0" 
        dataProvider="{myData}" labelField="DMV_VALUE_1">
</s:List>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

Also I am not getting any results to show up in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set the property to be [Bindable](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cc5.html):

```
[Bindable(event="myDataChanged")]
private function get myData():ArrayCollection{
 ...
}
```

Since you do not have a 'set' method defined.  As such, whenever the 'myData' changes you will have to manually dispatch the myDataChanged event in order for Bindable to have an affect.

I suspect that you will also have to make myData() a public property; otherwise how will the classes that make binding work be able to introspect into your custom component in order to access the property.

Overall, it looks like you are choosing a very bad implementation approach.  Is it is unusual to use a get method to make a database call and process the results.  It much more common to encapsulate such code out of your view; and pass the result data into the view.  There are many different ways to do this.  You could do it with a singleton approach, or a dependency injection framework, or dispatching events from a service class with the result data.

Comment: Ok so I added the bindable event but the results from the query do not show up in the view.  What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Did you step through your code to make sure the get method is dispatched? Does a 'myDataChanged' event ever get dispatched?  If not; then Binding will never take affect.

Comment: I stepped through the code and it never goes farther than x.parameters[":id"] = id;.

Comment: Sorry I got that fixed but it is stuck at var result:Array = conn.stmt.getResult().data;

Comment: If it never goes farther than a certain line of code; that means you have some type of bug in your code that you need to fix. Do you have the debug version of Flash Player installed so that you can see the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Yeah but apparently someone was overriding errors so that they wouldn't show up in certain cases and that's why that error wasn't showing.

Comment: I'm not sure what "overriding errors." means.  But, errors can be caught whether by the uncaughtException handler or using a try/catch block.  That may be what was happening to you.  If possible, I recommend modifying code to display information to the user (or yourself) when such an error is caught

Comment: Basically someone was coding for benign errors so that they wouldn't be caught.  But regardless I got it fixed.